# Insert new datagridview row on contextmenu button

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a contextmenustrip that enable user to insert ne row on a gridview. I want whenever the user click on the insert option in the contextmenu, new row will be insert after the current index selected.

[image]

I did it like this.

```
private void insertRowToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1, row);
}
```

But it doesnt work. Anyone please help me. TQ

Comment: what is `row` in your code?

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw you can ignore that line because it has error.

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

This method works only if you have not set datasource to the DataGridView control.

```
int iRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
```

iRowIndex will holds the index number of added row.

`DataGridView.Rows.Insert()` is basically used to insert a DataGridViewRow in DataGridViewRowCollection on specific location. for example if you have already entered 10 rows in grid and you want to add another row after row number 5 then you can use this function .

if your grid is bound then you can do like this. When grid is bound to datasource then you cannot add row pro grammatically to grid. You need to add row in the datasource and the row will be added automatically in the DataGridView.

**For DataView**

```
DataView dv = (DataView)dataGridView1.DataSource();
DataRowView dvr = dv.AddNew();
```

**For DataTable**

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource();
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
//dr["columnname"] = Assign Value for each column
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

**For DataSet**

```
DataTable dt = ((DataSet)dataGridView1.DataSource()).Tables[TableNameOrIndex];
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
//dr["columnname"] = Assign Value for each column
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Comment: It works fine when the data grid are empty, But theres data on the gridview, it display this error : Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.

Comment: You could not add row in the datagridview when you have set the datasource for datagridview. if you want to add another row then you should add it in DataSource object

Comment: @Ren what is the type of datasource assigned to datagridview? Is it DataView or DataTable?

Comment: It is datatable. is it possible to do this?

Comment: @Ren yes, I have updated my answer please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to insert a blank row, try this

```
If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
    DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index)
End If
```